# Does the HTML 'ID' tag allow UTF-8 encoded characters?

Tags: html, utf-8

What I mean is, is it valid to have html tag like this

```
<div id="t_реклама">Some text</div>
```

And second question, if this is not legal, then would the urlencoded version (like percent-encoded) value be allowed?

Also, will Javascript have problem parsing value of utf-8 id?

Comment: It looks like Chrome does not have any problem with utf8 in the value of id, even JS extracts the value correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is allowed:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: For what it’s worth, this changed in HTML5 ( http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-id-attribute ) to any collection of characters without spaces (U+0020 SPACE, "tab" (U+0009), "LF" (U+000A), "FF" (U+000C), and "CR" (U+000D))

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the reason you want to do this is to store some information in the HTML to retrieve later.

If that's the case, try using a custom HTML attribute:

```
<div id="myDiv" data-myattribute="t_реклама"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's a way to get some data from the database and add it to the page in such a way that it can be used by Javascript. Using costom tag seems to be good idea, still not sure if Javascript will have problem matching utf-8 values.